# Java web security solutions

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jboss, spring-security, java-ee-5

I am looking for some possible solutions for my web application security.

The web application redirect the user to the login server. Then after authentication is successful the user will be forwarded back to a certain page within my application. The login credentials are forward with the user. My page is served via a controller that authenticates the user for my application. (Authentication is accomplished using Liberty ID-FF 1.2.)

Currently, I am using Spring 3 page interceptors for the redirection.

My question is; How can I accomplish this with Spring Security? Or, is there another comparable framework? I like Spring Security for how easy it is to configure and how it protects the resources. To use it I need to have the authentication controller redirect the user to the login server. How do I do that in the authentication controller?

I am using JBoss 4.0.5, Spring 3.0, Java EE 5, and ID-FF 1.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid there is any support for Liberty ID-FF in Spring. Currently, there is SAML2 extension module only available for Spring Security.

More info:

http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/extensions.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I'm not interested in the implementation of Liberty ID-FF. I would like to find out if there is a way to use Spring Security and have the Authentication Controller redirect the user to the login server.

Comment: I got you, I don't think there is a way.